# How does the form designer instantiate the controls in a partial class without instantiating the fields declared in the outer part?

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, partial-classes

I have a form in Winforms that contains the following code :

```
//MainForm.Designer.cs
partial class MainForm 
{ 
   ...

   private void InitializeComponent()
   {
      ...
   }
}

//MainForm.cs
public partial class MainForm : Form 
{
     readonly form = new AnotherForm(); //won't be called by designer
}
```

What I found out: once the form is opened in Visual Studio, the form designer will initialize everything declared in `InitializeComponent()` (as it should) but won't instantiate `AnotherForm` (which is OK behavior but weird on a pure C# point of view).

I'm just wondering how it works. It feels like the designer is able to instantiate a partial class without calling constructor and initializing all fields declared in that class. It this something possible with reflection ?

Comment: The Designer *interprets* the content of `InitializeComponent()` to deserialize the components described there (see the notes in [CodeDomSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.serialization.codedomserializer)). The class itself is not fully constructed